# How can I invoke aquamacs from command line (OSX iterm) to open a file at a given line number?

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I can invoke `aquamacs` from `OSX iterm` command line no problem.

`aquamacs myfile.txt` works as expected.
However passing it a line number to open at does not work: 
`aquamacs +22 myfile.txt` also opens a new file called "+22" !!

How do I open a file at a particular line number? 
e.g with `vi` you can do `vi +23 myfile.txt` to open the file at
line 23

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@tingfengxia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11513022/tingfeng-xia) Aquamacs command line helper `aquamacs` is broken. (I believe it's fixed on trunk.)

`aquamacs` is basically a wrapper around macOS's `open`, so you can just do by hand what `aquamacs` is doing. Assuming you have `Aquamacs.app` properly installed

```
open -a Aquamacs myfile.txt --args +22
```

will do what you want. That is, open `myfile.txt` and move the cursor to line #22.

Note, that because of the way that `open` works, this will only work when starting a fresh Aquamacs session. If you already have Aquamacs running, and try do

```
open -A Aquamacs my_other_file.txt --args +39
```

Aquamacs *will* open `my_other_file.txt` in a new bufer, but it *will not* move to line #39. *Any arguments* will, in fact, be ignored.

I should add that Aquamacs does come with an associated `emacsclient` that works just fine. Provided you've run `server-start` in your Aquamacs session (either via your init file, or manually) you can then do

```
/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c +22 ~/myfile.txt
```

This will create a new GUI window (ie Aquamacs frame) associated with the current Aquamacs session, with myfile.txt loaded in its buffer, and the cursor at line #22. The full path to Aquamacs's `emacsclient` is obviously dependent on where you installed Aquamacs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not supported by aquamacs. The command line aquamacs can only take in one argument which is the file name, and this is why you are creating a new file called "+22" when you do `aquamacs +22 myfile.txt`.

You may find [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Going-to-a-line-by-number.html) helpful.